# Why maven causes dependencies errors?

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies, m2eclipse, pom.xml

Why some maven dependecies in the `.pom` file are causing errors like: `Missing artifact nonfree-lingpipe:lingpipe:jar:2.3.1`? All dependencies are listed in the .pom file. In .m2 folder I have all dependency folders, but not all jars: so for the `nonfree-lingpipe:lingpipe:jar:2.3.1` - there is no jar, but I have one for `4.1.0`. Why maven did not that one, but search for the `2.3.1`? I don't see any occurrence of the version in the `.pom` file, only the name.

Answer (score 0):

Maven dependencies have to have a version number specified. If you can't see one listed then you must have a [dependency management](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) element within your POM or one of its parents:

```xml
<project>  
  ...
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>nonfree-lingpipe</groupId>
        <artifactId>lingpipe:jar</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  ...
</project>
```

To make the change to 4.1.0, you must either specify the version explicitly in your dependency declaration or hunt out the dependency management section and make the change there.

Answer (score 0):

The definition in [dependencyManagement](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) defines only the artifact in which verison it should be used but does not really use this artifact. Furthermore the given Example:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>nonfree-lingpipe</groupId>
    <artifactId>lingpipe:jar</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

is wrong, cause the artifactId should never contain a colon. The right way would be:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>nonfree-lingpipe</groupId>
    <artifactId>lingpipe</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Furthermore you need to define this dependency outside the dependencyManagement block to really use this dependency.